# Get FileCodeModel for non-project files

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, envdte

I am developing a vsix extension for `Visual studio 2017` and i try get FileCodeModel for cpp-language files:

```
DTE dte = (DTE)this.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(DTE));

Document activeDoc = dte.ActiveDocument;
if (activeDoc == null)
    return;

ProjectItem projItem = activeDoc.ProjectItem;
if (projItem == null)
    return;

FileCodeModel fcm = projItem.FileCodeModel as FileCodeModel;
```

If the open file is not contained in the solution projects (they are int "Misc Files" project), then `fcm` is null. How can i get not-null `FileCodeModel` for files from "Misc Files" project?